# I can't get the description part in NestJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, jsdoc

[image: click here to see the screenshot]

Hello everyone. In the trainings I watch, this explanation comes out of everyone, but it does not come out to me. I tried all the plugins but couldn't make it. How can I handle this. Thanks in advance.

Hello everyone. In the trainings I watch, this explanation comes out of everyone, but it does not come out to me. I tried all the plugins but couldn't make it. How can I handle this. Thanks in advance.

PS

I use vscode. I've tried all the plugins related to NestJs. In all tutorials, this comes out when they move the mouse cursor between the e.g. Controller ( | ).

Comment: Please add more detail. What editor are you using? What extensions did you install that might enable this?

Comment: I use vscode. I've tried all the plugins related to NestJs. In all tutorials, this comes out when they move the mouse cursor between the e.g. Controller ( | ).

Comment: Are you just trying to get this hint block to pop up?

Comment: Yesss! and it can also be autocomplete. @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JSDocs and is coming from the `node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/core/controller.decorator.d.ts`

If you Ctrl + Click on `@Controller` (Go to Definition) you should get:

```
/**
 * Decorator that marks a class as a Nest controller that can receive inbound
 * requests and produce responses.
 *
 * An HTTP Controller responds to inbound HTTP Requests and produces HTTP Responses.
 * It defines a class that provides the context for one or more related route
 * handlers that correspond to HTTP request methods and associated routes
 * for example `GET /api/profile`, `POST /users/resume`.
 *
 * A Microservice Controller responds to requests as well as events, running over
 * a variety of transports [(read more here)](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics).
 * It defines a class that provides a context for one or more message or event
 * handlers.
 *
 * @see [Controllers](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)
 * @see [Microservices](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/basics#request-response)
 *
 * @publicApi
 */
export declare function Controller(): ClassDecorator;
```

This means that you have `@nestjs/common` package installed in your local repository.

**Ensure you have no conflicting VS Code Extensions/Snippets/Plugins installed.**

Comment: I can't see this block, and when I press CTRL and click on the function, I can't go there either. where am I at fault?

Comment: `npm i --save @nestjs/common`
Have you installed this package?
Are you able to build the project using `npm run build` ?

Comment: Heyy, I got it done. I noticed that I didn't have the node_modules folder. I think I made a mistake because I chose Yarn in the first time, so I couldn't do that. Now I have chosen npm packet manager and everything works. Thanks!